# Source for ACPI Power State: soft-off

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, acpi

We suffer from unpredictable server shutdowns (Fujitsu, 2k8 R2). The only unusual message in the logs are:

```
2018/06/29 13:14:13 [03006A] ACPI Power State: soft-off (S5 - by override) (INFO) CSS: no
```

sometimes 50 in a row, every 20-30 sec. These messages also apprear, when OS is alread shut down (I assume, the source is not in the OS or an application).

Fujitsu Support changed HDD, RAID controler and mainboard, we changed PSUs, but the error persists.

I ask myself, if there is anything in the network traffic that causes the server to switch to S5 (soft-off)?

Any ideas what to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until today no indication for something bad in network traffic. Fujitsu support changed front panel (with main switch) and problem seems to be fixed.